# Generating a numpy array with cumulative slices

Tags: python, numpy

It's a basic problem that I am trying to solve using NumPy (avoiding loops). Given a number n, I want to generate all the ranges starting from 1 to every i between 1 and n.

So,

> if n is 2 then the expected output is [1, 1,2]

> n = 4 then expected output is [1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4]

I can solve it easily with a list comprehension, but is there a completely vectorized way that I can use?

```
[j for i in range(1,5) for j in range(1,i+1)]
```

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: One thing I am testing out is something with summing upper triangular matrices (with 1s and 0s) for each slice but to get those slices itself is something I am trying to figure.

Comment: Look at the code for the `tri....` family of functions.  But in general a rectangular array layout is better suited to 'vectorization' than a triangular one.  If you have arrays of differing length vectoriztion is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does exactly what you need

```
def generate_sequence(k):
    return np.tril_indices(k)[1] + 1
```

Imagine you have the following array

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
```

And you want to keep the elements

```
0 . . . .
0 1 . . .
0 1 2 . .
0 1 2 3 .
0 1 2 3 4
```

These happen to be the lower triangle elements and they have the indices (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), etc. It so happens that the column component of the indices literally generates the sequence 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, etc. And you just have to shift it by 1.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Was thinking in the same lines but didnt think about tril indices, instead was focusing on tril ! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  np.arrange inside list comprehension, will save one loop iteration

```
array =[list(np.arange(1, i+1)) for i in range(1,5)]

[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```